# Angular queryParamMap is empty, then populated

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have created a new module in my app so I can separate parts that do not have to communicate and created an new.module.ts with its own routing module and components :

`new-routing.module.ts`:

```
const exportRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'export',
    component: ExportsComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(exportRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ExportRoutingModule {}
```

`new.module.ts`:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

// Routing Module
import { NewRoutingModule } from './new-routing.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., ExportRoutingModule, ...],
  declarations: [ExportsComponent],
  bootstrap: [ExportsComponent]
})
```

I have a simple `index.html`:

```
<body class="app">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> // outlet is here because I read that I needed it to be able to use activated route, I actually just want the query params
</body>
```

and finally, where the problem lies, my component :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(
(params: ParamMap) => console.log(params) 
// Do stuff with params => error)}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/export?firstParam=1.00,2.00,3.00` in my console, the `params` are logued twice, once empty, once populated as such :

```
ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}
keys:(...) // empty
params:{} // empty

core.js:3565 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}
keys:Array(3)
params:{firstParam: "1.00,2.00,3.00", secondParam: "bla"}
```

This cause my component to throw error since I need those params to display my component and the first time they are logued they are empty so :

- Why are they loggued twice ?
- Why is my code executed before my params observable has a value ?
- Could I get rid of the router outlet (which I don't really need since I have no routing involved with this module, I just used it because I read that I couldn't use `activatedRoute` without it; I just want the query params from my url

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll offer 2 solutions to this problem, first, using the `skip` operator :

Since Activated Route is a BehaviorSubject so first we'll get an empty value, then the actual queryparams so we can skip the first value :

*(note, this solution uses lettable operators, hence the `pipe()`, if you are not using lettable operators you can just chain it like you would do any other rxjs operators : `.skip(1)`*

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() 
    {this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(
    (params: ParamMap) => console.log(params)}
```

Second solution, use a regular javascript function to retrieve the params :

```
ngOnInit() {
  const token = this.getParameterByName('access_token');
  console.log(token);
}

getParameterByName(name: any) {
  let url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[[]]/g, "\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
  results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/+/g, " "));
}
```

I'll point you to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/8370200) for the original code

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @Lakston does not take into account the flow when there's no query params and we need to detect it. After struggling a lot I found a real solution for those of us working with SSR (Server Side Rendering, meaning no browser global objects available for us) and in need of detecting the no query param scenario.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
----------------------------------------------------------
constructor(private location: Location)
----------------------------------------------------------
let questionIndex = this.location.path().indexOf('?');
questionIndex = questionIndex === -1 ? Infinity : questionIndex;
const queryParams = (<any>Object).fromEntries(this.location.path().substr(questionIndex + 1).split('&').filter(str => str).map(el => el.split('=')));
```

All credits to YugasVasyl, who posted this answer on: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157

I already test it on my project and it works!
Blessings...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using the `ExportsComponent` for bootstrapping:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [ExportsComponent]
})
```

The component you specify here is used when the application starts, so it's `ngOnInit` is called early.

What you can do is to have a separate component for bootstrapping and separate `ExportComponent`, here is an example (see [the live version](https://plnkr.co/edit/WmRRmPyJ3xbp3AlfqqEh?p=preview)):

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { RouterModule, Router, Routes, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule, Component, OnInit }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <nav class="rbe-plunk-nav">
      <ul>
        <li> <a [routerLink]="['/']">Homepage</a> </li>
        <li> <a [routerLink]="['/about']">Export</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <!-- The router will put the content here, right after the outlet -->
    </main>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: '<h1>Home: </h1>'
})
export class HomeComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'export',
  template: '<h1>Export: </h1>'
})
export class ExportComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
         console.log("Export: ");
         console.log(paramMap);
     });
  }
}

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',         component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about',    component: ExportComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { /*enableTracing: true*/ }
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ExportComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  // Diagnostic only: inspect router configuration
  constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer ! I've actually found two working solutions to the empty params problem, I posted an answer to illustrate both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Url: http://localhost:4200/licenca-filtro?param=60&param2=50

component.ts

```js
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {

    const param1 = this.route.queryParams['value']['param'];
    const param2 = this.route.queryParams['value']['param2'];
    
    console.log(param1, param2);

   }
```

OUT: 60 50